# Python - Printing an ASCII cartesian coordinate grid from a 2D array of position objects

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, class, ascii

Terribly sorry, all, but this is going to be a long one.
So as an off-shoot of my previous inquiry regarding STDIN, unfortunately it doesn't appear there are many similar enough questions to my specific issue, at least not in Python (nor without using something like numpy which is a touch above my level). I do have plenty of code which I've already implemented, so hopefully that will help (although it's not the cleanest and as I mentioned above it's rather long).

My issue, as it stands, is with printing out ASCII-art representing a 2D array of class objects such that the ASCII accurately depicts them in the orientation of a simple x,y Cartesian coordinate grid.

I have several classes interacting with each other, the first of which constructs position objects containing two integers, representing the x and y of a Cartesian coordinate pair:

```
class Pos:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

The second class constructs a 'square' grid from some size parameter provided by the user in a different part of my program, implemented here as a 2D array filled with these position objects:

```
class Grid:
    def __init__(self, size):
        assert size > 0
        self.size = size
        self.grid = []
        #1  Perhaps there is something wrong with my 2D implementation...
        for x in range(size):
            sub_grid = []
            for y in range(size):
                sub_grid.append(Pos(x, y))
            self.grid.append(sub_grid)
```

Also within this class is a method which prints out ASCII-art of the grid to act as an external representation for the user (this is the messy bit):

```
def print(self):
    #  This is the main ASCII-art.
    size_check = self.size - 1
    if self.size > 10:
        print('   +' + ('-' * (((self.size * 2) + 1)) + '+'))
    else:
        print('  +' + ('-' * (((self.size * 2) + 1)) + '+'))
    counter = 0
    #2  ...or perhaps it's something wrong with this iterative condition.
    for x in self.grid[::-1]:
        if self.size > 10:
            if size_check > 9:
                print(self.size - 1 - counter, '|', end=' ')
            else:
                print('', self.size - 1 - counter, '|', end=' ')
        else:
            print(self.size - 1 - counter, '|', end=' ')
        counter += 1
        size_check -= 1
        for y in x:
            #  This is only here to check if the coords are in the correct position in the art.
            ^^if y.x == 5 and y.y == 8:
                print('O ', end='')^^
            else:
                print('. ', end='')
        print('|')
    if self.size > 10:
        print('   +' + ('-' * (((self.size * 2) + 1)) + '+'))
        print('     ', end='')
    else:
        print('  +' + ('-' * (((self.size * 2) + 1)) + '+'))
        print('    ', end='')

    #  This is simply support for grid sizes greater than 10.
    if self.size > 10:
        for x in self.grid:
            if x[0].x <= 9:
                print('', '', end=' ')
            elif x[0].x > 9 and x[0].x < (self.size - 1):
                strng = str(x[0].x)
                print(int(strng[0]), end=' ')
            elif x[0].x == (self.size - 1):
                strng = str(x[0].x)
                print(int(strng[0]))
        print('     ', end='')
        for x in self.grid:
            if x[0].x <= 9:
                print(x[0].x, '', end='')
            elif x[0].x > 9 and x[0].x < (self.size - 1):
                strng = str(x[0].x)
                print(int(strng[1]), end=' ')
            elif x[0].x == (self.size - 1):
                strng = str(x[0].x)
                print(int(strng[1]), end=' ')
    else:
        for x in self.grid:
            if x[0].x < (self.size - 1):
                print(x[0].x, '', end='')
            elif x[0].x == (self.size - 1):
                print(x[0].x, end='')
    print()
```

I know this is a lot, but what it successfully prints out looks like so (given size = 10):

```
  +---------------------+
9 | . . . . . . . . . . |
8 | . . . . . . . . . . |
7 | . . . . . . . . . . |
6 | . . . . . . . . . . |
5 | . . . . . . . . . . |
4 | . . . . . . . . . . |
3 | . . . . . . . . . . |
2 | . . . . . . . . . . |
1 | . . . . . . . . . . |
0 | . . . . . . . . . . |
  +---------------------+
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Now this looks just fine, until I try to show where the position objects are supposed to be located. In the above code I marked with ^^ a conditional statement which prints out an 'O' at the coordinates (5, 8). The result looks like so:

```
  +---------------------+
9 | . . . . . . . . . . |
8 | . . . . . . . . . . |
7 | . . . . . . . . . . |
6 | . . . . . . . . . . |
5 | . . . . . . . . O . |
4 | . . . . . . . . . . |
3 | . . . . . . . . . . |
2 | . . . . . . . . . . |
1 | . . . . . . . . . . |
0 | . . . . . . . . . . |
  +---------------------+
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

The ideal output should actually look like this:

```
  +---------------------+
9 | . . . . . . . . . . |
8 | . . . . . O . . . . |
7 | . . . . . . . . . . |
6 | . . . . . . . . . . |
5 | . . . . . . . . . . |
4 | . . . . . . . . . . |
3 | . . . . . . . . . . |
2 | . . . . . . . . . . |
1 | . . . . . . . . . . |
0 | . . . . . . . . . . |
  +---------------------+
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

As you can see, the ASCII-art is printing in such a way that externally it *looks* as if the x and y axis have swapped, even though internally the coords at any position object respond correctly. I wrote two comments in the above code where I speculate what the issue might be. My best guesses being either how I implemented the grid itself, or how I'm printing the art; but that's what I need help figuring out.

Any and all help is, as always, wholly appreciated; and I apologize once again!

Comment: It's mixing up rows and columns in your variables. A mistake as old as computer programming itself.

Comment: Of course it is; it's always something so simple. Unfortunately you will have to forgive my upcoming ignorance: Where exactly is it doing that? Is it in the creation of my grid or the printing like I originally speculated, or is it something else that I'm just missing?

Comment: Just insert many many print statements and see at which point the results are incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest building your lines using string manipulation instead of printing directly.  This will make the code simpler and allow for substitution of patterns within a template string for the typical line content.

For example:

```
# prepare the empty content
rows = 10
cols = 10
content = [["."]*cols for _ in range(rows)]

# assign values at coordinates as needed (based on your grid)
content[5][8]  = "O"
grid = [(4,1,"H"),(6,3,"L"),(5,2,"E"),(4,6,"R"),(7,4,"L"),(6,6,"W"),(3,6,"L"),(2,6,"D"),(5,6,"O")]
for (y,x,c) in grid: content[y][x] = c

# build frame
width       = len(str(max(rows,cols)-1))
contentLine = "# | values |"

dashes      = "-".join("-"*width for _ in range(cols))
frameLine   = contentLine.replace("values",dashes)
frameLine   = frameLine.replace("#"," "*width)
frameLine   = frameLine.replace("| ","+-").replace(" |","-+")

# print grid
print(frameLine)
for i,row in enumerate(reversed(content),1):
    values = " ".join(f"{v:{width}s}" for v in row)
    line   = contentLine.replace("values",values)
    line   = line.replace("#",f"{rows-i:{width}d}")
    print(line)
print(frameLine)

# x-axis numbers
numLine = contentLine.replace("|"," ")
numLine = numLine.replace("#"," "*width)
colNums = " ".join(f"{i:<{width}d}" for i in range(cols))
numLine = numLine.replace("values",colNums)
print(numLine)
```

output:

```
  +---------------------+
9 | . . . . . . . . . . |
8 | . . . . . O . . . . |
7 | . . . . L . . . . . |
6 | . . . L . . W . . . |
5 | . . E . . . O . . . |
4 | . H . . . . R . . . |
3 | . . . . . . L . . . |
2 | . . . . . . D . . . |
1 | . . . . . . . . . . |
0 | . . . . . . . . . . |
  +---------------------+
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

output with rows=12 and cols=15:

```
   +----------------------------------------------+
11 | .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  |
10 | .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  |
 9 | .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  |
 8 | .  .  .  .  .  O  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  |
 7 | .  .  .  .  L  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  |
 6 | .  .  .  L  .  .  W  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  |
 5 | .  .  E  .  .  .  O  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  |
 4 | .  H  .  .  .  .  R  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  |
 3 | .  .  .  .  .  .  L  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  |
 2 | .  .  .  .  .  .  D  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  |
 1 | .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  |
 0 | .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  |
   +----------------------------------------------+
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14
```

Comment: My apologies, I should have clarified that my Pos class has another attribute 'self.used = False' (I didn't think it was relevant to my question) thus using the position objects is necessary so if I manipulate them the ASCII can update accordingly. The periods where simply placeholders as an example for what will be a grid filled with all manner of characters like 'O', 'A', etc., because these objects can be arranged into various shapes. As much as I love this answer, others have already pointed out my mistake in swapping my rows and columns. Nevertheless, you can have an upvote.Thank you!

Comment: I was running out of characters; what I mean is that your answer could very well help someone who might have a similar issue to mine, but would perhaps benefit from a more indirect form of manipulation. It never hurts to help, just as it never hurts to ask. Which is precisely why I always sign off with: "Any and all help is always appreciated!" Because it really is, and when I comment I do my best to make sure people know how grateful I am, because I'm an absolute sap.